How can I have a different method instead of user.is_authenticated?
I have an academy website , which has 3 different kinds of users. The first one is the staff that I handle with the admin panel. The second one is parents or people who are going to get some information about the academy. The third one is students who have a different panel.
My question is how can I authenticate this students ? I mean we have a method that is  {% user.is_authenticated %} but it isn't ok for me because I want to check a different model named "students" and I used this method for other places.
I expect a different authentication system. Because the one which I used is for regular users and I want to check that if he is a student he can have access to the special panel. Please share your ideas.

Try customizing your user model or adding a model with one to one field to the user, store the necessary information you need to figure out what role your user has and use those to limit / provide appropriate access.
